# Can any class object be passed as test expression for any test expression such as if, while like ifstream object.

Tags: c++

In C++, can I use my objects as test expression like `ifstream` objects. If not, why?

e.g.

```
ifstream ifs ("myfile.txt");
while( ifs ){
   //read and process data..
}
```

I have a class, which operator do I need to overload to let compiler allow my object to be passed as test expression?

e.g.

```
MyClass obj1;
if( obj1 ){
   //do something..
}

while( obj1 ){
   //do something repeatedly..
}
```

Both should be valid expressions.

Comment: `operator bool() { return ?; }` would work. It cast an object to a bool. In the first example i normally see `while(ifs >> c) {}`

Comment: Check out: [Safe boolean Idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool). Remember though it is deprecated in C++11.

Comment: The default font in your questions should not be bold.

Comment: @AlokSave Idioms aren't part of the standard, and so cannot be deprecated.  C++11 does provide as simpler and clearer means of doing the same thing (and the article you cite goes a bit overboard---the classical solution is `operator void*`), but nothing's been deprecated.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You are correct perhaps **obsolete** is the correct word.

Comment: Thanks Andre, Alok.. Going through provided link.. Just could not figure out which operator to overload at first place..

And Andre if we have to just overload bool operator, it means that operator is automatically called to evaluate objects to boolean, RIght..!!

Comment: @Angew

I'll keep that in mind..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options you have. Probably best one is to overload the `operator bool()`. Like so:

```
class A{
 public:
   operator bool()
   {
     return flag;
   }

 private:
   bool flag;
};
```

EDIT: as pointed out in the comments if you use `C++11` it is better to make the operator explicit by adding the `explicit` keyword to the front. Otherwise probably it is better to use the `operator void*()`

Comment: Probably the best one is using C++11 and having that operator explicit. Second best is the safe bool idiom.

Comment: Without the `explicit`, you should use `operator void*()`, or something similar.

Comment: operator void *()..?? Can you explain which operator are we overloading..!!

Comment: Note that it should be either `explicit operator bool() const` (C++11) or `operator void*() const` (anything else).  Just `operator bool()` is _not_ a good idea.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the above is the absolutely worst of all possible choices. So it does not surprise that it's selected as "the solution".

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement a `bool` overload in your class. Something like this:

```
class myClass {
    public:
        explicit operator bool() const { return condition; }
};
```

It will work both in `if` and `while` statements. However, if your compiler does not support C++11 you can't use the `explicit` keyword in this overload.

Comment: If C++11 is available, it's a good idea to make the operator `explicit`.

Comment: @ash_1 It's new as of C++11. If your compiler doesn't support it don't use that keyword with this overload.

Comment: @David `explicit` isn't new to C++11.  Being able to use it on an implicit conversion operator is.  And without `explicit`, you really shouldn't use `operator bool()`.  (And even with `explicit`, it should be `const`.  A convertion to `bool` that changes the value of your object is _not_ going to make your code easier to understand.)

Comment: Is there any way we can do this without it..

I'll look for explicit keyword... Any link suggestion to learn that..??
There should be some way to do this without explicit keyword.. We write ifstream objects as test expression on compilers that do not support explicit...

Thanks that was helpful any way..!! Still looking for more info on this..

Comment: @JamesKanze I should have worded that better. My bad. ;)

Comment: @ash_1 The classical solution was `operator void*() const`, returning a null pointer or a non-null pointer.  If you're paranoiac, you can even make it a pointer to a type the client code cannot name, but just making it a `void*` is usually sufficient enough---we're protecting against Murphey, not against Machiaveli.

Comment: @James Kanze 
opearator void *() const ..?? I didn't understand.. which operator we are overloading here..??

Comment: @David
Thanks..

I'll try both.. with and without explicit...

And sorry that I cannot click answer was useful..(Reputation point is too low to do that :( )

Comment: @ash_1 The type conversion operator.  In one case, you're converting to `bool`, in the other to `void*`.  In the unlikely case that you can count on C++11, `explicit operator bood() const` is the way to go.  Otherwise, `operator void*() const` will work just as well.

Comment: @James Kanze Okay.. Got it now.. Its explict operator bool().. Just a typo..!!
nice and clearly explained..!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options.

You don’t have to implement an `operator bool` overload in your class.

And it’s generally not the best choice.

---

### Best: named state checking.

The best is to use a ***named*** state checking method. For example, iostreams have the `fail` member, so that you can write

```
while( !cin.fail() ) { ... }
```

For your own class it can look like this:

```
struct S
{
    bool is_good() const { return ...; }  // Whatever name.
};
```

---

### So-so: `explicit` conversion to `bool`.

Next best is a `explicit` conversion operator. Having it `explicit` prevents if from being called inadvertently for passing one of your objects as a function argument. An `explicit` conversion operator is still used in a *condition*, so you can write e.g.

```
while( cin ) { ... }
```

which in C++11 invokes an

```
explicit operator bool () const { return !fail(); }
```

For your own class it can look like

```
struct S
{
    explicit operator bool () const { return ...; }
};
```

---

### Ungood: implicit conversion to "private" pointer type.

Third, if you're using a compiler that does not support `explicit` conversions, i.e. a C++03 compiler, and if for some inexplicable reason you do not want the named checking which is the best choice, then you can choose a result type that minimizes the chance of an inadvertent call.

In C++03 iostreams used an implicit conversion to `void*` (instead of to `bool`).

Some people advocate using the "safe bool idiom" where the result is a pointer to an, in C++03, type that's inaccessible to client code.

---

### Absolutely worst: implicit conversion to `bool`.

The worst option of all is like

```
struct S
{
    operator bool () { return ... }
};
```

With this

- One cannot see from calling code what condition is being checked.
- The operator can be inadvertently called for passing an `S` as function argument.
- The conversion can not be called on a `const` object.

Adding a `const` only makes it slightly less bad.

It’s still very bad. :-)

Comment: For a user defined class, except in exceptional cases, I agree with your first point.  Except that as a predicate function, its name should probably start with `is...`.  (The standard sets some very poor examples when it comes to naming.  `std::vector<>::empty()`, for example, doesn't empty the vector as one would expect, and `std::ios_base::good()` is not the opposite of `std::ios_base::bad()`.)  Something like `MyClass::isValid()` or `MyClass::isDone()` is far more appropriate.

Comment: THanks..Nicely explained..!!

Answer (score 0):

It is `operator bool()` you need to overload to provide this behaviour. But please only do this if there is a sensible semantic meaning to the conversion, that is obvious and expected by all users of the class!

Comment: Thanks Sam Holloway..
I just wanted to know how it can be done.. Just a random question came into mind.. C++ lab guide could not answer..
(Sorry can not mark useful answer, Reputation point is too low..)

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler will attempt to implicit cast the expression to **bool**, so you will need to add a [typecast operator](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/) to your class, like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    operator bool() {
        return true; // a boolean expression should go here.
    }
}
```

this will allow for your class to be casted to a boolean type and therefore let it be used in *if*, *while* etc...
It is however important to note that this allows implicit conversions from your type to **bool** and it is important to make sure that this makes sense.

Often it is more sensible to provide a method for the behavior, such as:

```
while (myObj.hasMoreElements())
```

or

```
if (someObj.isValid())
```

This makes it immediately clear what is being tested. However, if a conversion to **bool** makes sense, go for it.

Comment: Thanks rmhartog..

Methods are a good way to that.. 
If c++ compiler does that with ifstream.. My object should also be able to do that..
.
Just Wanted to learn how was it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload any number of type conversion operators; the
traditional one was `operator void*()() const`, to return a null
pointer for false, and a non-null pointer (tradiionally `this`)
for true.  In C++11, you can also overload `explicit operator
bool() const`, but this is not recommended if your compiler
doesn't yet allow `explicit`; the fact that `bool` is an
integral type, and that without the `explicit`, it will convert
to any other integral type, can lead to some surprising overload
resolutions .

If you do this, you should also overload `operator!() const`, so
that `if ( ! myObj )` is well defined as well.

And finally, you should really reflect as to whether you want to
do this.  The ostream classes get away with it because they're
part of the standard, and *everyone* sees, uses and knows them,
and the `while ( someStream >> object )` idiom is ubiquitious.
But on the whole, it's misleading and an abuse of operator
overloading for any class which has more than two possible
states; an `isValid` or `isReady` or whatever function is more
appropriate.

Comment: sorry can not mark as useful.. Reputation point too low..!! :(

very clearly explained.. You should teach us in college in spare time..!!